# Which is the git command equivalent to SVN synchronize?

Tags: git

Here my GIT local repository cloned from distant repository with the files at time T:

```
A.txt
B.txt
C.txt
```

At time T+1, the files at remote repository (the tracked one) :

```
*A.txt*
C.txt
D.txt
```

We see that, A.txt has been modified (I put *), B.txt has been deleted and D.txt was added.

Question : What is the git command that outputs (one line for one file) on my local post :

```
* A.txt (modified)
- B.txt (deletion)
+ D.txt (add)
```

To summarize, I want to output the diff between my local repo and the remote tracked one. One line for one file (for readibility reason)

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare your local to a remote, you first have to fetch.  Usually that's just

```
git fetch
```

At that point `git status` would give you a very rough summary of how far ahead/behind you are, but to really know what's changed you'd do something like

```
git diff --stat origin/master master
```

(This is assuming the remote is set up as `origin` in your local repo, which is the typical/default case.)

Comment: OK thank you. Is it the usual way to work with GIT ? I often did synchronize with SVN to update and resolve conflict file by file or group of file.

Comment: Yes, this is the usual way to work with git. (If you have a remote repository at all, it's the only way to work with git; and if you collaborate with other developers - which is a key consideration in git's design - then you need a remote repository...)  It may seem odd to not always know the state of the remote, but in truth git is just giving you the *option* to operate without remote communication (for various reasons; mostly bc it helps git be ridiculously fast).  If you need constant updates from the remote, you can fetch whenever you want; but you'll probably find you don't need to.

Comment: Ok. In fact, I find this procedure a bit boring or fastidious. Should I do it only when it is worthwhile (this is informative output after all) ? For example, 'git merge' or 'git rebase' works automatically (like does the SVN synchronize tool menu) in 99% case otherwise it prompts to resolve a conflict manually that git can't solve automatically. Am I right ?

Comment: I guess the relevant difference from SVN is that in git, a merge or rebase combines two *local* lines of work (which is possible because the entire repo is local).  So the merge operation itself will usually work automatically, but the merge itself is a local operation; if you're merging work from a branch that's in the remote, you'd fetch to get the branch into your local repo first.  (The sort-of exception is that in some workflows you'd trigger a lot of merges implicitly with a `git pull`; and since `git pull` *also* implicitly does a fetch, that might look more like what you're used to.)..

Comment: ... But even if this may be an extra step, it has advantages.  The merge doesn't affect the remote repo until you push, so if something goes horribly wrong you can easily undo it locally without having affected anyone else.  It's really just about getting used to the separation between local operations and remote operations.  (In short: only fetch, pull, and push involve the remote; and pull only involves the remote in that it implicitly does a fetch.)

Comment: Thanks you Mark for your participation. I needed to understand more precisely the GIT philosophy. Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

you can use the command `git status`

Comment: As simple like that. I was looking for git log or git diff. Thank you.

Comment: @FrançoisF. - `git status` won't give the detail you asked for, and won't tell you anything at all if you haven't done a `git fetch` first.  So actually not as simple as that.

Comment: Ok so what it will outputs in this use case (comparison with remote repo)  ?

Comment: But you don´t actually compare with a ¨remote¨. You compare (with git diff, for example) with revisions (which could be pointed to by [optionally remote] branches/tags). So if you want to see what the changes are with a remote branch you could do: ```git diff --name-status remote/branch-name```

Comment: @FrançoisF. - Not sure what your last comment is asking, but maybe this explanation will help: If you clone a remote, then do nothing to change the local repo (nor fetch), then git status will always say you're up to date with the remote branch regardless of what happens on the remote.  To see the changes from the remote, you must `git fetch`; and then status is still very summary-level, just saying "your master branch is x commits behind origin/master" or something like that. `git status` doesn't tell you "file 1 was modified, file 2 was deleted, etc."

Comment: What @Edmundo says is more precisely correct - that you never compare against the remote really.  The only ways git lets you interact with a remote are fetch, pull, and push (and the interaction during pull is really just a fetch).  That's why fetching and then immediately comparing remote refs to local refs is the closest thing you can do to what you're asking.